# Unable to receive Client Secret using keycloak admin cli endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using the following endpoint:
`http://localhost:8083/auth/admin/realms/Myrealm/clients/ltiobf/client-secret`

and getting the response as

```
{
  "error": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized"
}
```

I am getting the access token from Keycloak using the following:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/Myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
    --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
    --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'postman-token: de7d68a0-5b21-1405-ed1a-9b7a6cb0da25' \
    --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=Sqb7zNt9Bk8OAx4vEjhjUDKQU_qw6K9B4jjJq69i.magistrate; XSRF-TOKEN=c620bf0f-a46a-41b4-bc30-558e96422123; JSESSIONID=gDz-86p4prmLkl12O7kx-8FdIcSAErBYhKitm5r8; JSESSIONID=Sqb7zNt9Bk8OAx4vEjhjUDKQU_qw6K9B4jjJq69i.magistratehq' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=ltiobf' \
    --data-urlencode 'username=sairaj1417' \
    --data-urlencode 'password=sairaj123' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

and passing it as an Authentication parameter in the GET request for client secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token should be one requested on behalf of a user with the proper permissions to request Tokens omitted by Keycloak:

```
curl    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
        -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
        -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
        -d "grant_type=password" \
        https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

with the `admin-cli` as the client `ID`. From that response (*i.e.,* a Keycloak Token Object), extract the access token, let us named `$ACCESS_TOKEN`.

If you have access to the `Admin` console you can easily get the `client secret` by going to:

- your `Realm`;
- then click on `clients` and select your `client`;
- Go to the tab `credentials` there you have it.

However, if you want to do it using the Keycloak Rest API, first you need to know the `ID` of the client, which can be obtained using :

```
curl -X GET https://<KEYCLOAK_IP>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME/clients?clientId=<CLIENT_ID> \ 
            -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

(the `<CLIENT_ID>` is basically the client name) from that response you need to extract the desired `ID` of the client. With that `ID` you can extract the client `secret`, using:

```
curl -X GET https://<KEYCLOAK_IP>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME/clients/<ID of the client>/client-secret \ 
            -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

---

I have created scripts in this [repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Clients) to automatize this process so that the community can use them as they wish.